# Change the encoding of extracted queries in slqplus

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I am executing in shell script a simple command to extract the content of query in a file.

```
sqlplus -s /@P2AX << EXIT > /temporary/test.csv
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss';
select *
from japhonie.ad_contacts
where con_id = 3720;
EXIT
```

The problem is that my base contains japanese characters. The current encoding in the db is SJIS (classic encoding for japanese language). So my output file */temporary/test.csv* is automatically in SJIS too. But I would like to have it in UTF-8. Is there any command I could add to my shell script to extract directly the content of my query in UTF-8? or do I have to do it after extraction?

Comment: probably would be easier to run some converter - after the file is generated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have extracted the file without mojibake, I think it is better to convert `/temporary/test.csv` to UTF-8.

In Linux environment, the command below will help you.

```
iconv -f Shift-JIS -t UTF8 /temporary/test.csv > /temporary/test.csv.utf8
```